# Windows batch file for ADB Shell Run Iperf

Tags: batch-file, adb

I am trying to write a windows batch file that will open my ADB Shell...then write one command and execute within the adb shell, not the windows command prompt. I am trying to figure out how I get the batch to write the command after opening the adb shell into that prompt instead of command prompt. When I attempt it now, it opens the adb shell but then writes the command I am trying to execute in command prompt instead of the adb shell.

This is what I would manually do after opening my windows command prompt.

```
cd\
cd adb
adb shell
iperf -s -u -il -p0001 - this line is written in the adb shell prompt $ to open particular port for data
```

Any help for this newbie would be much appreciated.

Comment: how did you install iperf? I can't run it on adb

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
adb shell "iperf -s -u -il -p0001"
```

Put your shell command in quotes. For instance if I want to run an app on my android phone I will write:

```
adb shell "am start -n com.package.name/com.package.name.Activity"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try and pipe the command into the shell. Your complete batch would look like this

```
cd\
cd adb
iperf -s -u -il -p0001 | adb shell
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How would I write that in the batch file exactly then? I currently just use this command in the batch file to start the adb shell   START /MAX D:\adb\adb shell   Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show the whole batch file, just copy and paste and run :)

Comment: I tried it out. Unfortunately it still will not run the command in the adb shell prompt. Thanks anyways.